# What is a actual meaning of procedure?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

```
SQL> create or replace procedure print()
  2  is
  3  begin
  4  dbms_output.put_line("This is a print procedure");
  5  end;
  6  /

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.
```

According to me.. the procedure doesn't return any value which means it is a void function. Then this should work. It should print "This is a print procedure".

Comment: In PL/SQL a procedure is not a "void function".

Answer (score 8):

> According to me.. the procedure doesn't return any value which means it is a void function. Then this should work. It should print "This is a print procedure".

Well, that's not how it works. It is actually *according to Oracle* as database sets rules here, not you.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure print()
  2  is
  3  begin
  4    dbms_output.put_line("This is a print procedure");
  5  end;
  6  /

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.
```

As you use SQL*Plus, the simplest way to see what's wrong is to *show errors*:

```
SQL> show err
Errors for PROCEDURE PRINT:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
1/17     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the
         following:
         <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
         current delete exists prior

SQL>
```

It says that you used brackets where they shouldn't be used (line 1). When brackets are removed, then:

```
SQL> l1
  1* create or replace procedure print()
SQL> c/()//
  1* create or replace procedure print
SQL> l
  1  create or replace procedure print
  2  is
  3  begin
  4    dbms_output.put_line("This is a print procedure");
  5* end;
SQL> /

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.
```

What's wrong now? Double quotes in line 4; single quotes are used in Oracle:

```
SQL> show err
Errors for PROCEDURE PRINT:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
4/3      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
4/25     PLS-00201: identifier 'This is a print procedure' must be
         declared

SQL>
```

Let's fix that:

```
SQL> l4
  4*   dbms_output.put_line("This is a print procedure");
SQL> c/"/'/
  4*   dbms_output.put_line('This is a print procedure");
SQL> c/"/'/
  4*   dbms_output.put_line('This is a print procedure');
SQL> l
  1  create or replace procedure print
  2  is
  3  begin
  4    dbms_output.put_line('This is a print procedure');
  5* end;
SQL> /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

OK, *now* it is OK. Does it work? Enable output first!

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec print
This is a print procedure

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Yes, it works.

---

However, I'm not sure whether you understand that creating procedure won't automatically execute it. You said

> It should print "This is a print procedure".

Of course it shouldn't; if everything went well in the first place, you'd get `Procedure created.`; after you execute it, you'd get actual message, `This is a print procedure`.